# Global Colour Definition in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I'd like to define some colours to use throughout my app. I'm a bit new to this, so I'm not quite sure where to put my colour definition.

I can define a colour as:

```
lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48/255 green:160.0/255 blue:255.0/255 alpha:1.0];
```

But where do I put that, in order to use it throughout my app?

Apologies if this is a ridiculously easy question, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the *global* color using [Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2). Firstly, create a new file in Xcode, choose **Objective-C File** this time. Next type,

- File: MyColor (for example)
- File Type: Category
- Class: UIColor

Now you have your own category which is generated by Xcode and you can add custom methods and properties in `UIColor` without subclassing it. Here is a example to add the color you want:

In **UIColor+MyColor.h**

```
+ (UIColor *)myLightColor;
```

In **UIColor+MyColor.m**

```
+ (UIColor *)myLightColor 
{
    static UIColor *myLightColor = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t dispatchToken;

    dispatch_once(&dispatchToken, ^{
        myLightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255 green:160.0/255 blue:255.0/255 alpha:1.0];
    });

    return myLightColor;
}
```

Whenever you need to use your custom color in other files, just import `UIColor+MyColor.h`, and use the color like this:

```
self.aTitle.textColor = [UIColor myLightColor];
```